# ajax result showing error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple problem but I couldn't find out the solution.
the below code is my POST ajax code.

once Its submitted I got the result from the PHP file. 
once this alert is work `alert(addcenterresult);`

if OK its alerted 1 if not 2 
but the result if every time showing `alert ("SomeThing Wrong");`

I checked my PHP everything is good. I assumed the error in my ajax code but I found nothing !!!

**Please can you help**

```
$('#add-jeddah').click(function () {
    var centername = $('#JeddahCenterNAme').val();
    var dataString = 'centername=' + centername;

    if (centername == '') {
        alert("Please write the center name");


    } else {
        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "func/addjeddahCenter.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (addcenterresult) {
                alert(addcenterresult);
                if (addcenterresult == "1") {
                    alert("Well Done");

                } else {
                    alert("SomeThing wrong");
                }
            }
        });


    }

    //  END add-Jeddah function
});
```

My PHP

```
$nameCenter = $_POST['centername'];
$addresult = "INSERT INTO centers (id,centerName) VALUES ('','$nameCenter')";

if (mysql_query($addresult)) {
    echo "1";
        } else {
             echo "2";
    }
```

Comment: post your PHP code as well.

Comment: Where is the mysql connection statements in your php code?

Comment: @Apb Done already :)

Comment: specify the `dataType:text` or parse the result

Comment: it's included from another file. The problem not with the data because the PHP insert function is working good The data inserted to the Databased. but the ajax result is not. @SanjayKumarNS

Comment: I tried it but the result still goes wrong @guradio

Comment: @ammoriz what have you tried?`dataType:text`?

Comment: try  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) to find out what is the actual error

Comment: @ammoriz what are you returning anyway maybe you are getting `2` from php?

Comment: Can you remove all codes from the php file and add echo "1"; and check

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS Yes I used echo "1"; only and the ajax worked !

Comment: @guradio I'm getting 1 from the PHP because   alert(addcenterresult);
showing 1

Comment: @ammoriz did you add `dataType:text, `?

Comment: @guradio yes but no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the jquery trim when you match the condition equal to 1 or 2 ,sometimes whitespace is returned with the string

give a try to following lines

```
if ($.trim(addcenterresult) == "1") {
    alert("Well Done");
} else if ($.trim(addcenterresult) == "2"){
    alert("SomeThing wrong");
}
```

This would also verify that the response you receive is either between 1 or 2 only.

Comment: Thanks @ammoriz , i am glad to help solving your issue :)